# How to programmatically modify width of elements in Grid, When in XAML it is set with *

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have defined two columns with separator like this:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Name="sideBar" Margin="{StaticResource SplitLeft}"   SizeChanged="ScrollViewer_SizeChanged">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="LEFT CONTENT" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" />
            <TextBlock Text="" Name="ShowThings"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" />
    <ScrollViewer Name="ListPage" Grid.Column="2 " Margin="{StaticResource SplitRight}" SizeChanged="ScrollViewer_SizeChanged">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="RIGHT CONTENT" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Content goes here" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

so the page is divided in 1:2 proportions. but if user wants to resize it, he can. I want to persist the modified width in app settings to be used for next launch.

on size change event I am storing the new width in settings,

```
    Properties.Settings.Default[((ScrollViewer)sender).Name + "Width"] = e.NewSize.Width;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

and in window constructor loading the settings and setting the values.

```
    sideBar.Width = (double)Properties.Settings.Default["sideBarWidth"];
```

but this does not work. can anyone help me identify the problem? I am sure this is a duplicate question, but I don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to set the `Width` of your `sideBar` if it is depending on the size given in the [`Grid.ColumnDefinitions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.columndefinitions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try to set the `ColumnDefinition.Width`:

```
// 0 = first column
grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength((double)Properties.Settings.Default["sideBarWidth"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. That does make sense. but follow up question. grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width is System.window.GridLength type. how to convert double width, which is pixels I guess to GridLength.